# Parametrize query in t-sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, prepared-statement

```
SELECT TOP @columnCount @columnName 
FROM @tableName
```

I get the following error

> Incorrect syntax near '@columnCount'.

What could be wrong?

If I change to

```
SELECT TOP (@columnCount) @columnName 
FROM @tableName
```

I get the following error

> Must declare the table variable "@tableName".

I run it from C#

Comment: Passing the field names as parameters doesn't make much sense - parameterized queries are about reusing execution plans. Changing the fields can completely change the optimal execution plan. You can use `TOP(@someParam)` from SQL Server 2008 R2+

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A safe and secure way would be

```
DECLARE @columnCount INT = 100
DECLARE @columnName  NVARCHAR(128) = 'YourColumnName'
DECLARE @tableName   NVARCHAR(128) = 'YourTableName'

DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @Sql = N'SELECT TOP (@columnCount) ' +  QUOTENAME(@columnName) + N' 
            FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@tableName)

EXECUTE sp_executesql @Sql
                     ,N'@columnCount INT'
                     ,@columnCount
```

Answer (score 2):

You need dynamic SQL to accomplish what you're trying to do.

```
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(max);
SET @sql = 'SELECT TOP ' + @columnCount + ' ' + @columnName + ' FROM ' + @tableName;
EXEC(@sql);
```

The variables used need to be converted appropriately.

Read more in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx)

Comment: Will this not throw an error as @ColumnCount Variable is most probably an `Int` variable :) and also this code is vulnerable to SQL Injection Attack.

Comment: @M.Ali *"The variables used need to be converted appropriately."*

Answer (score 1):

Column lists and Table names cannot be parameters. However, since you are running this from C# you are technically already using Dynamic SQL (unless you are calling a stored procedure with those params but there is no mention here of stored procedures being used so for now I will assume not).  When building the SQL in C#, you need to concatenate the Column List and Table Name into the query but you can still use a parameter for the value used by the TOP() operator:

```
SqlConnection _Connection = new SqlConnection("connection string");
SqlCommand _Command = new SqlCommand();
SqlDataReader _Reader = null;

string _Query;
string _TableName = "dbo.MyTable";
string _ColumnList = "Field1, Field2 AS [AliasedName], Field3";
int _NumberOfRows = 12;

_Query = String.Concat("SELECT TOP (@NumberOfRows) ",
    _ColumnList, " FROM ", _TableName);

SqlParameter _NumRows = new SqlParameter("@NumberOfRows", SqlDbType.Int);
_NumRows.Value = _NumberOfRows;

try
{
    _Connection.Open();
    _Reader = _Command.ExecuteReader();
    // do stuff
}
finally
{
    _Reader.Close();
    _Connection.Close();
}
```

Of course, you could also just concatenate the @NumberOfRows value directly into the query as well, but keeping it as a parameter will allow for Query Plan re-use if running this query multiple times with the same values for ColumnList and TableName but changing the @NumberOfRows value.